# redirect to a link stored on mysql server using php login system

Tags: php, mysql, apache, session, cookies

So I know this question has been asked multiple times on here, however I've been staring at my code for hours and need a new pair of eyes to look over my error.

Now I know that mysql_* is depreciated in php 5.5 but in IT world we are taught that if something isn't broke then don't break it. On to the problem

I have a login system in php that seems to work on one of my domains but not the other one. The code is identical on my other server that uses the same login system, however it does't seem to work on my second server (perhaps php.ini config problem?). Basically the login_success.php file is suppose to redirect users to a link stored inside the mysql database.

the links look like this on phpmyadmin: [image]

Here is my index file for the login:

```
<?php
session_start();

function loggedin()
{
 if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) || isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
 {
        return true;
 }
else {
            return false;
     }
}

if (loggedin() == true)
{
   header("Location: /login_success.php");
   exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database_name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table_name"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$rememberme=$_POST['rememberme'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) //user exists
{
  if ($rememberme=="on"){
      setcookie("myusername", $myusername, time()+7200);
   }
 elseif ($rememberme==""){
      $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
   }

header("Location: /login_success.php");
exit;
}
else {
echo '<div class="alert">Incorrect Username or Password!</div>';
}
}
?>
```

Here is my login_success.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
// IF USER NOT REMEMBERED(DID NOT CLICK REMEBER ME BUTTON) OR NO SESSION IS FOUND THEN THROW HIM OUT TO LOGIN
//SECURITY SO THAT USERS CANT ACCESS WEB URL DIRECTLY
 if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && !isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
 {
   header("Location: index.php");
 }

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="database_name"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table_name"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT target_address, username FROM $tbl_name");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$LOCATION = $row['target_address'];
if ($_SESSION['myusername'] == $row['username'] || $_COOKIE['myusername'] == $row['username'] ){
header("Location: $row['target_address']");

}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: So what is the actual question or the error (on the second server)?

Comment: Does it work? :) header("Location: $row['target_address']"); ???

Comment: @dollarvar on the second server I can access login_success without logging in and login_success does not redirect to the link inside mysql server. On the first server it works perfectly (i.e. can't access link manually and redirects after login)

Comment: @AliMasudianPour yes it does work on my original server with the same code

Comment: What PHP version does the original server have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
header("Location: $row['target_address']");
```

change it to:

```
$url=$row['target_address'];
header("Location: ".$url);
```

Comment: Why? What does it change?

Comment: Works!, however I'm confused as to why my code works on one server and not the other? Any ideas?

Comment: @dollarvar Umm, we have a syntax error here! But new php versions might skip this

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But I do not know what in older versions is different, is this a thing about "not parsing variables in double quotes? Hmm, what version is the first server in @fixnode?

Comment: BTW: This would have done it too `header("Location: {$row['target_address']}");` but I do not know nothing about the working of it on the first server!?!

Comment: And this `header("Location: $row[target_address]");` hmmm

Comment: The original server has PHP version 5.5.8 and this server has 5.5.3 so it's slightly older version.